# Как загрузить дамп базы 1ГБ?

Tags: веб-сервер, консоль

Как загрузить бекап базы 1ГБ?

Знаю, что через консоль, но в какую папку сам файл.sql класть?

Comment: Я там ответил но теперь думаю, что я не правильно понял вопрос. Что Вы понимаете под словом "загрузить" в данном случае?

Comment: @KryDos, правильно поняли. Верный ответ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неважно в какой папке файл. Вам просто нужно будет указать путь к нему.

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < путь/к/файл.sql
```